# Select query arithmetic calculation

Tags: mysql, sql, join, division

I would like to make some basic calculations with a select query.
I have a table called Distances, and there is an attribute saved distance.
I would like to calculate distance of Customer1/Sum of distances of Customer1, Customer2 and Customer3.
Is this kind of a query formally right:

```
select ((select Distances.distance from Distances
         where Distances.CustomerID='1') /
        (select SUM (Distances.distance) from Distances
          where Distances.CustomerID IN ('1', '2', '3')) as ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to use the Distances table twice.

```
select cust1.Distance / sum(allCusts.distance)
from distances cust1
cross join distances allCusts
where cust1.CustomerID = '1'
and allCusts.CustomerID in ('1','2','3')
group by cust1.Distance
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when d.CustomerID = '1' then d.distance
           end) as Cust1Distance,
       sum(case when d.CustomerId in ('1', '2', '3') then d.distance
           end) as Cust123Distance
from distances d;
```

If you are only looking at those three customers, then adding `where d.CustomerId in ('1', '2', '3')` should make the query more efficient.